# May one tell a Gentile to drive his car immediately before Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

During a recent Shulchan Aruch lesson, I learned that one may not tell a Gentile tailor immediately before Shabbat to fix a suit that he will need immediately after Shabbat, as this is clear that he will be doing the work on Shabbat for him. This falls under the prohibition *Amirah Lenachri* ("telling a Gentile".)

Extending this - let's say one is driving home with a Gentile friend in one's car. He and his friend live in the same neighborhood. He sees that it is approaching sundown on Friday. He pulls over and asks the Gentile to drive his car. Is this considered *amirah lenachri*, as we know that the Gentile will be driving his car on Shabbat?

Or, can we reason that they are just sharing the driving and let's say the Jew says plainly, "it's your turn to drive, now", without specifying anything relating to Shabbat, that this would make it permissible to ride in the car and it is not *amirah lenachri*? Perhaps, we can also reason that his friend also wants to get to his home, as well. Thus, driving the car is not specifically to benefit the Jew.

Please focus the answer to just the *amirah lenachri* issue. There may be other peripheral problems of doing this, such as *mar'it ayin* when the Jew arrives home.